# How to Handle Facebook Application Requests?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Handle Facebook Application Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384804/how-to-handle-facebook-application-requests)

I am working on a Facebook application And I am offering the user to invite his friend to the application using the C# SDK. as shown in  [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

My problem is when the friend of the user receive the application request and click **Accept**  it does not show the `application permission request page`.

Do I need to preform any extra step to redirect the user to the `application permission request page`?

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.